# MQTT Creates Multiple connections when onCreate is called more than once

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

I am creating an instant messaging system using Paho Android MQTT Client. Its implementation works as expected, however I am facing these errors.

I call the `Connection Class` ( This also calls for the creation of the connection to the broker) in the `onCreate` of the `MainActivity Class`.

Now the problem is that, assuming I am on the `MainActivity Class` and I press back to move from the `MainActivity Class` to another activity, and I later come back to the `MainActivity Class`, another broker connection will be created. This will mean that anytime a single message is published, the client will receive the message twice.

**MainActivity.java:**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_intera);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    dbHelper = DatabaseManager.getInstance(context);
    //mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.history_recycler_view);

    connections = new Connections();
    connections.createConnectionForPublishing(context);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("LOG: Service destroyed");
}
```

}

**Connection.java**

```
public class Connection {

    public void createConnectionForPublishing (final Context context) {

        //Instantiate the mqtt android client class
        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient (context.getApplicationContext (), serverUri, clientId);


        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback (new MqttCallbackExtended () {

            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {
                if (reconnect) {
                    System.out.println ("Reconnected to : " + serverURI);
                } else {
                    System.out.println ("Connected to: " + serverURI);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost (Throwable cause) {
                System.out.println ("The Connection was lost.");
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived (String topic, final MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                System.out.println ("Message received and Arrived");
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete (IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                System.out.println("Message Delivered");
            }
        });

        final MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions (); 
        mqttConnectOptions.setMqttVersion (MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect (true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession (false);

        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.connect (mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener () {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess (IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    System.out.println ("BROKER CONNECTED");

                    DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions ();
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled (true);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize (100);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer (false);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages (false);

                    //mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts (disconnectedBufferOptions);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure (IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    System.out.println ("Failed to connect to: " + serverUri);
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

I am new to MQTT, I would be glad if somebody can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then if you don't want to establish the connection multiple times you'll have to make it as singleton to have only 1 instance of the connection class and one time connection established.

So your code will become:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.chat_intera);

        Connection connection = Connection.getInstance (getApplicationContext ());
    }

    // ....
}
```

**Connection.java**

```
public class Connection {

    private       static Connection          connInst;
    private       static boolean             connected;

    private       static MqttAndroidClient   mqttAndroidClient;
    private       static IMqttActionListener mqttActionListener;
    private final static MqttConnectOptions  mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions (); 
    static {
        mqttConnectOptions.setMqttVersion (MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect (true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession (false);
    }

    private Connection (Context context) {
        //Instantiate the mqtt android client class
        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient (context.getApplicationContext (), serverUri, clientId);

        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback (new MqttCallbackExtended () {

            @Override
            public void connectComplete (boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {
                connected = true;
                if (reconnect) {
                    System.out.println ("Reconnected to : " + serverURI);
                } else {
                    System.out.println ("Connected to: " + serverURI);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost (Throwable cause) {
                connected = false;
                System.out.println ("The Connection was lost.");
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived (String topic, final MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                System.out.println ("Message received and Arrived");
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete (IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                System.out.println("Message Delivered");
            }
        });

        mqttActionListener = new IMqttActionListener () {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess (IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                System.out.println ("BROKER CONNECTED");

                DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions ();
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled (true);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize (100);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer (false);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages (false);

                //mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts (disconnectedBufferOptions);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure (IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                System.out.println ("Failed to connect to: " + serverUri);
            }
        });
    }

    public static Connection getInstance (Context context) {
        if (connInst == null) {
            connInst = new Connection (context);
        }
        createConnectionIfNeeded (context);

        return connInst;
    }

    private static void createConnectionIfNeeded () {
        if (connected) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.connect (mqttConnectOptions, null, mqttActionListener);

        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The multiple connections are still being created

Comment: @George, how do you know they have been created? or share your whole code. (onResume etc...)

Comment: Check my update above, I have updated the `MainActivity Class`, that is how I use it

Comment: Ok. 1- replace your code with mine. 2- How do you know multiple connections are being created?

Comment: I have Done same, I have replaced my codes with yours. `System.out.println ("BROKER CONNECTED");` Prints multiples of `BROKER CONNECTED` This is what tells me it is creating in multiples

Comment: I'm not sure about that, it should be called only once unless, somehow you're reconnecting. Verify the code of `connectComplete` as this method is not on the docs and post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135134/discussion-between-george-and-mehdi-b).

Comment: it seems to work when I added the `CreateConnectionIfNeeded` in the condition statement like this     `public static Connections getInstance (Context context) {
        if (connInst == null) {
            connInst = new Connections (context);
            createConnectionIfNeeded(context);
            System.out.println("CONNECTION WAS NULL");

        }else {
            System.out.println("CONNECTION WAS NOT NULL");
        }
        return connInst;
    }`

Comment: @George, please try to put `connected = true/false` respectively on `onSuccess/onFailure`

Comment: But is my submission wrong, adding `createConnectionIfNeeded(context);` to the IF condition

Comment: @George, well, it should be handled by the condition of the `if (connected) { return`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think maybe a null check can help that

```
if (connection == null){
   connections = new Connections();
   connections.createConnectionForPublishing(context);
}
```

Comment: And do you need the MQTT client only in that activity? If not maybe you should close the connection at the activity's onPause void. As I see here 

http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/android-javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/android/service/MqttAndroidClient.html

there is a close void for the MqttAndroidClient objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you set a flag using Android `onPause()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()

And then instead of using `onCreate()`, use `onResume()` to  initiate your MQTT connection but check `onPause()` flag first.

You may also need to close the connection in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`. Look at lifetime of an Android application/activity for more info.